# "JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json" executing jar but mvn:exec works

Tags: java, json, web-services, maven

I have an issue trying to package my maven project. I developed and tested it using mvn:exec and all works fine.
With the following pom.xml I generated jar file with dependencies (using mvn package). Application starts fine but when I send a request to a JAX-RS webservice on the log i get this:

```
[2015-11-25 16:55:05] [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo] SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, ....
```

For simpler objects like Strings or ints, on the client side I got "415 - Unsupported Media Type" for json.

I already tried adding json-media-moxy to dependencies or executing jar with java -cp instead -jar but nothing worked.

Here is my pom:

```
[...]
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        [...]
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>it.project.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>it.project.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

Solved! Just adding

```
rc.register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

to my ResourceConfig to get things work. I don't know why but with mvn package and jar execution jersey does not execute auto discovery, so jackson wasn't registered.

Comment: For viewers trying to understand why this is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36687730/4178025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Just adding

rc.register(JacksonFeature.class);
to my ResourceConfig to get things work. I don't know why but with mvn package and jar execution jersey does not execute auto discovery, so jackson wasn't registered.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this dependency (adapt to your jersey version)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

I guess there is not the jersey required library in order to handle json data in maven dependencies

**UPDATE**

My mistake, I have just see that you already have it. How are you doing your request? with a custom client? If you are using a custom client try this

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

Comment: no my client is angularjs (so user browser) but even with curl or intellij tool result is the same.