# jersey-media-json-jackson not included in jar

Tags: java, json, maven

I try build maven-project in NetBeans. In project I use jersey-media-json-jackson. My dependencies look like that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And if I run project in IDE all work correctly. But if I build project with dependencies and run resulting jar-file I am having the following error

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.ats.orion.client.model.req.UpdateContextRequest, genericType=class com.ats.orion.client.model.req.UpdateContextRequest.
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.ats.orion.client.model.req.UpdateContextRequest, genericType=class com.ats.orion.client.model.req.UpdateContextRequest.
```

The same exception appear in IDE when I comment jersey-media-json-jackson dependency.

My build block in pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.ats.test.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How to solve my problem?

Comment: I hope you are running the `jar-with-dependencies` and not the default jar generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be happening because of the way Jersey discovers and registers features automatically. Putting everything into a fat jar can cause issues with this auto-discovery and registration and you might have to do it manually.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687312/jersey-fails-when-creating-uber-jar-with-maven-assembly-plugin) answer to a very similar question, only in your case the statement to register Jersey's Jackson feature would probably be

```
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
                "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                "org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
```

Comment: Thanks! Your link was helpful. Using maven-shade-plugin fixed my problem.