# Get errors when launching jar (maven compiled), but simple run on Intellij works fine

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, jersey

The project on Intellij works fine, with dependencies for com.sun.jersey server, core and json defined in the pom.
Then I created the jar (to do that I had to move the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from /src/main/java to /src/main/resources), which appears to be ok (in the folders embedded in the jar I can find all the right dependencies under maven).
Then I launch the jar and it starts correctly ... but, at runtime, when the program tries to get a json from a rest api, I get the following error:

```
May 10, 2018 9:33:25 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
GRAVE: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found
May 10, 2018 9:33:25 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
GRAVE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:630)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
        at com.dataCollection.executor.Downloader.download(Downloader.java:49)
        at com.dataCollection.executor.Downloader.run(Downloader.java:34)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

For some reason it doesn't find the media type application/json. But when I launch the main class from Intellij it works fine.

Here is the piece of code in which the program calls the remote service:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://...(correct address)...");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
```

Here is the pom:

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>CollectDataFromREST</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <dependencyReducedPomLocation>
                            ${java.io.tmpdir}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
                        </dependencyReducedPomLocation>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.acme.coyote</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>hidden.coyote</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.dataCollection.StartDataCollection</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml file

Comment: done, the pom is now in the post

Comment: That's the whole pom? You aren't using any other plugins like the assembly plugin to create a fat jar?

Comment: I added in the pom the maven-shade-plugin, but the result is exactly the same

Comment: try [adding the transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36687730/2587435)

Comment: tried, same result